# How can we execute parallel payments and refunds in stripe php?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Payment to one account is possible using the below code but the method of parallel payment is seeming ambiguous.

And how the refund process would work? For that we'll have to save the credit card details of the user in whose account the refund has to be made.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>Wilde Things</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/normalize.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="container">
            <?php
            require_once('../stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
            $stripe = array(
              'secret_key'      => 'sk_test_gRNo5PZ1TVjxRv9crUhw92lu',
              'publishable_key' => 'pk_test_lsE6QUL6t2mDTJ64S9EXL5Nh'
              );

            Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

            if ($_POST) {
              $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                'card'     => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                'amount'   => 53500,
                'currency' => 'usd'
                ));

              $wildeQuotes = array(
                "A little sincerity is a dangerous thing, and a great deal of it is absolutely fatal.",
                );
            }
            else
              { ?>
            <h2>Wilde Things</h2>
            <h3>Purchase a quote by Oscar Wilde today! Only $535! Limited supply and going fast, buy now!!</h3>

            <form action="index.php" method="post">
              <script src="https://button.stripe.com/v1/button.js" class="stripe-button"
              data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
              data-amount=53500
              data-description="One Wilde quote"
              data-label="Buy"></script>
            </form>
            <?php
          }
          ?>
        </div><!-- #container -->
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with parallel payments but with the refund, when a Stripe Charge is made, it will return an ID and Stripe will store the credit card details. So when it comes refunding (if needed), all you need is the ID to process the refund.

Comment: Can you just brief me how the refund method would be processed?
And with parallel payments I mean that transferring payments to multiple accounts simultaneously.

Comment: http://code-brew.com/projects/gambay/stripe_test/Step1/index.php

You can check the process